# How to apply a threshold to a pandas DataFrame column and output a row outside of the threshold?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, threshold

I have a large dataset of product families. I'm trying to catch any weird data entries where a price is too high/low than the other members of the family. For example, I have a this `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
df =
Prices    Product Family
0    1.99        Yoplait
1    1.89        Yoplait
2    1.59        Yoplait
3    1.99        Yoplait
4    7.99        Yoplait
5    12.99       Hunts 
6    12.99       Hunts 
7    2.99        Hunts 
8    12.49       Hunts
```

I want to write a for loop, that iterates through each Product Family, sets some kind of threshold which identifies which products are questionable (row 4 and row 7), and spits out that row. How can I do this?

So far I have this:

```
families = df['Product Family'].unique() 
for i in families: 
   if df['Prices] .....(set threshold)
   then.....(spit out that row that is questionable)
```

And then I would ideally finish off that if statement in the for loop, for each product family. Does anyone have an idea (or a better one) on how to set this threshold and finish off the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using pandas it is best to not use loops if possible.  In your case we can use `groupby()` to do operations of like Families.  Here is one way to find your outliers by using values which differ from the group median:

#### Code:

```
df['median'] = df.groupby('Product_Family').transform('median')
df['outlier'] = ((df.Prices - df['median']) / df['median']).abs() > 0.5
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    Prices      Product_Family
    1.99        Yoplait
    1.89        Yoplait
    1.59        Yoplait
    1.99        Yoplait
    7.99        Yoplait
    12.99       Hunts 
    12.99       Hunts 
    2.99        Hunts 
    12.49       Hunts"""),
                 skiprows=1)

df['median'] = df.groupby('Product_Family').transform('median')
df['outlier'] = ((df.Prices - df['median']) / df['median']).abs() > 0.5

print(df[df.outlier])    
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
   Prices Product_Family  median  outlier
4    7.99        Yoplait    1.99     True
7    2.99          Hunts   12.74     True

   Prices Product_Family  median  outlier
0    1.99        Yoplait    1.99    False
1    1.89        Yoplait    1.99    False
2    1.59        Yoplait    1.99    False
3    1.99        Yoplait    1.99    False
4    7.99        Yoplait    1.99     True
5   12.99          Hunts   12.74    False
6   12.99          Hunts   12.74    False
7    2.99          Hunts   12.74     True
8   12.49          Hunts   12.74    False
```

Comment: This is great, makes sense! However I am getting an error on the line:

Comment: df['median'] = df.groupby('Product_Family').transform('median')

Comment: The error says: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: Under *Test Code*, I gave the exact to run.  Start there, and then make changes, to see what breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess my way is similar to Stephen Rauch's. Only difference is that I standardize/normalize the `prices` per group.

```
# Standardize or normalize the `Prices` per `ProductFamily` (absolute value)
df_std = df.groupby('ProductFamily').transform(lambda x: np.abs((x - x.mean()) / x.std()))

# We assume that any Price beyond one standard deviation is an outlier
outlier_mask = df_std['Prices'] > 1.0

# Split clean and outlier dataframes
df_clean = df[~outlier_mask]
df_outlier = df[outlier_mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also use quantiles for outlier detection with grouping and transformation as in other answers. Following uses 0.05 and 0.95 quantiles as limits:

```
# FIND LOWER AND UPPER LIMITS: 
df["lower"] = df.groupby("ProductFamily").transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.05))
df["upper"] = df.iloc[:,0:2].groupby("ProductFamily").transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.95))
print(df) 

# SELECT ROWS THAT MEET CRITERIA: 
df = df[(df.Prices > df.lower) & (df.Prices < df.upper)]
print(df)

# TO KEEP ORIGINAL 2 COLUMNS:
df = df.iloc[:,0:2]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Prices ProductFamily  lower  upper
0    1.99       Yoplait  1.650   6.79
1    1.89       Yoplait  1.650   6.79
2    1.59       Yoplait  1.650   6.79
3    1.99       Yoplait  1.650   6.79
4    7.99       Yoplait  1.650   6.79
5   12.99         Hunts  4.415  12.99
6   12.99         Hunts  4.415  12.99
7    2.99         Hunts  4.415  12.99
8   12.49         Hunts  4.415  12.99

   Prices ProductFamily  lower  upper
0    1.99       Yoplait  1.650   6.79
1    1.89       Yoplait  1.650   6.79
3    1.99       Yoplait  1.650   6.79
8   12.49         Hunts  4.415  12.99

   Prices ProductFamily
0    1.99       Yoplait
1    1.89       Yoplait
3    1.99       Yoplait
8   12.49         Hunts
```